# How to edit a attribute of all of the special html tags(like a)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I'm trying to to edit a attribute of all of the special html tags(like a) using c#. for example I want to change this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com"></a>
    <a href="http://gmail.com"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://go.go/default.aspx?url=http://google.com">
    </a><a href="http://go.go/default.aspx?url=http://gmail.com"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

It means I want to append the value of `href` in `<a>`

I tried LinqToXML but it didn't work because HTML is not valid XML(because of DOCTYPE tag)

it was my code:

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(s);

var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("html").Elements("body").Elements("a")
            select c;

foreach (XElement book in query)
{
    string atr = book.Attribute("href").Value;
    book.Attribute("href").Value = "http://ahmadalli.somee.com/default.aspx?url=" + atr;
}

xmlFile.Save(s);
```

and `s` was my html stream.

Does anyone know How can I do this?

**I want to have this code in ASP.NET**

Comment: I'm aware that it's not C#, but maybe jQuery would better suit your needs? However, it looks like you need to save the html contents. In that case, use HTMLAgility Pack as suggested below

Comment: @Bertvan: see I want to make all the link from my website. and then redirect the user to original website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

The download contains several sample projects - check them out to see how to manipulate an HTML file.

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee: it does not require asp.net, it's just your normal .net class library.

Comment: @Oded: How can I do this using HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee - Take a look at the samples in the download.

Comment: @Oded:but the sample is wrong! http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee - You need to read what I posted more carefully. When you download the HTML Agility Pack, with it, in the download, there are sample Visual Studio projects doing all kinds of things. Look at them, read them, learn from them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply search for every `http://` and `https://` and change them as you need.

You should use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` functions.

Read more about Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.aspx).

Here is a sample code:

```
string s; //store html content in this variable.

int i = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.InStr(1, s.ToLower(), "http://");
int j1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.InStr(i+1,s.ToLower(),"\""); 
int j2 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.InStr(i+1,s.ToLower(),"'");
int j;
if ((j1 < j2) && (j1 > i))
    j = j1;
else
    j = j2;

s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(s,1,i-1) + "http://www.go.go/default.aspx?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(s,i,j-i)) + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(s,j);
```

This code will change the first `http://` form real address to something that you want.

You can create a while loop and repeat this to replace every link. (remember to exclude `http://www.go.go/default.aspx?`!

Note that my code may need some little changes. (like maybe `i+1` instead of `i` or something like this!)

**EDIT : This way has some problems, for example, it doesn't support internal links. you should search for tags (e.g. `<a`) and process internal links inside it (until `>`).**

Comment: I think there is better way instead text processing.

Comment: I think that the best way is Oded's answer, but you said that you can't use that library.

Comment: no! I said my problem with Html Agility Pack [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9139156/1003464)

Answer (score 0):

Put runat="server" in the  tag as such:

```
<a runat="server" ID="linkGmail" ....></a>
```

Then in your code, you can change the value of href attribute as such:

```
linkGmail.Attributes["href"] = "http://go.go/default.aspx?url=http://gmail.com";
```

Comment: you didn't understand what am I said

Comment: Were you trying to parse the HTML and replace all occurrences of the attribute? I thought you meant that you want to replace the href attribute of the link from the code within the ASPX page.. is that not the case?

Comment: No.I'm downloading a html file(web page) in a `stream` then I want to change the `href` value of the links of that `stream`. I want to develop a project like `PHProxy` but using `.net`.