# why HTML Agility Pack HtmlDocument.DocumentNode is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using this code to change the href attribute of a HTML stream.

first I download a full html page using this code:(URL is webpage address)

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = 
                         (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Stream s = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

then I process this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(s);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/a"))
{
    string att = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
    link.Attributes["href"].Value = "http://ahmadalli.somee.com/default.aspx?url=" + att;
}
doc.Save(s);
```

`s` is html stream.

but I've got an exception that says `doc.DocumentNode` is null!

**i tried many sites but `doc.DocumentNode` is null to**

Comment: What does `s` look like?

Comment: Is it pointing to a full HTML document, or an HTML fragment?

Comment: And what is the structure of the HTML? Does is have an `HTML` element? A `BODY` element? Is it a valid document?

Comment: @Oded It depends on the webpage

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee, I cannot reproduce your error. `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes` could return `null` if no nodes found. It seems your xpath expression doesn't found any node and return null. Could you paste a full code which throws a `NullReferenceException` exactly on `doc.DocumentNode`?

Comment: @Alex: It is a method that loads a webpage and I tried many webpage addresses whit the code. in all cases the `doc.DocumentNode` is null!

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee: sorry, but I can't see how `doc.DocumentNode` could be `null` with the scenario you provided.

Comment: @Alex: It's the reason that I asked the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com?q=stackoverflow"));
    foreach (var href in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(x => x.Attributes["href"]))
    {
        if (href == null) continue;
        href.Value = "http://ahmadalli.somee.com/default.aspx?url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(href.Value);
    }
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    doc.Save(writer);
    var finalHtml = writer.ToString();
}
```

Also see the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`  to be able to get the url back correctly. Otherwise, some parameters in original url may cause problem.

Use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to decode it.

Comment: I tried your code but I've got an exception:`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee I run it on another machine. It worked without a problem.

Comment: First: I tried it using [this link](http://google.com) it worked fine! the I tried it using [this](http://codeplex.wordpress.org) and got a NullRefrenceException. `href` in foreach statement is null!

Comment: I added `if (href == null) continue;` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `//a` instead of `/a`.

In XPath, this basically means **give me all the links in the document**, as opposed to **give me all the links in the document *root***.

**Update:**

The following code works fine:

```
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
        var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        var s = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();

        doc.Load(s);
        foreach (var link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
        {
            var att = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
            link.Attributes["href"].Value = "http://ahmadalli.somee.com/default.aspx?url=" + att;

            Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: anyway  doc.DocumentNode is null and the exception thrown before of the foreach

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use `DocumentNode` at all? Why not use `doc.SelectNodes` directly?

Comment: @Oded: SelectNodes is a method of DocumentNode

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Can you give an example of URL for which this fails? Or just a basic structure of the HTML?

Comment: @w0lf: I tried your suggestion but after that I just got a empty Stream and my new Stream was null

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Try using `http://google.com` as the URL instead of just `google.com` (if you didn't do that already)

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee I've added a code sample that works (enumerates all links on the page)

Comment: @w0lf: first: I'm using http but stackoverflow comment doesn't show it. second: I tried your code but still an empty html like last try

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Try using a different URL or try to diagnose your network connection (see if you need to configure a proxy)

Comment: @w0lf: It's a asp.net and runs into my browser and I can connect to stackoverflow. the problem isn't from network connection

Comment: @w0lf: there is no proxy or internet problems in my connection.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee It's probably worth noting that Google will / does put temporary blocks on IP's if there are an above normal number of calls. This, might be causing you to get nothing returned from goog if you've been running the code a lot in a short space of time. You should probably try using some other urls for now, so as to eliminate that as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: [HTML Agility Pack Null Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801828/html-agility-pack-null-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument
        {
            OptionAddDebuggingAttributes = false,
            OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
            OptionFixNestedTags = true,
            OptionReadEncoding = true
        };
        try
        {
            using (Stream reader = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                reader.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                htmlDoc.Load(reader, true);
            }
            HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;
            if (node != null)
            {
                foreach (var href in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(x =>x.Attributes["href"]))
                 {
                     href.Value = "http://ahmadalli.somee.com/default.aspx?url=" +HttpUtility.UrlEncode(href.Value);
                 }
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

I am using HtmlAgility pack version: 1.4.0

Solved your problem? If no, please comment. Else mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag reference is an incorrectly escaped string:

```
...doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/a")    //incorrect
...doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")   //correct
...doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"/a")   //also correct
```

The original code fails to select any nodes and evaluates to null; this should be checked against to prevent failing on, say, a document where there are no links at all (however unlikely that is :)

```
var anchors = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
if (anchors != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode link in anchors)
    {
        /*do stuff*/
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is no difference in resulting strings between `"/a"` and `@"/a"`.