# NullReferenceException with HtmlDocument reference in C#

Tags: c#, unity-container, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack` in order to scrape information off of Google Translate for a translation program. I have downloaded the `HtmlAgilityPack` dll, and successfully referenced it in my program. I am using Assembly in Unity. Below is my code for the two programs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class GUIScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private string textField = "";
    private string input;
    public Texture2D icon;
    Dictionary search;
    Encoding code;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
        search = new Dictionary();
        input = " ";
        code = Encoding.UTF8;
        //This is what is run to translate
        print (search.Translate("Hola","es|en",code));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnGUI(){
        textField = GUI.TextField(new Rect(0, Screen.height -50, Screen.width-80, 40), textField);
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width-80, Screen.height -50, 80,40), icon)){
            input = textField;
            textField = "";

        }
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(0,Screen.height -70, Screen.width-80,20), search.Translate("Hola","es|en",code));
        //print (search.Translate("Hola","es|en",code));
    }
}
```

This is the code that references my `Dictionary` class shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


public class Dictionary{
    string[] formatParams;
    HtmlDocument doc;
    public Dictionary(){
        formatParams = new string[2];
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
    }
    public string Translate(String input, String languagePair, Encoding encoding)
     {
        formatParams[0]= input;
        formatParams[1]= languagePair;
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", formatParams);

        string result = String.Empty;

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Encoding = encoding;
            result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }       
        doc.LoadHtml(result);
        return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title=input]").InnerText;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
}
```

When running this, I receive the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Dictionary.Translate (System.String input, System.String languagePair,System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at Assets/Dictionary.cs:32)
GUIScript.Start () (at Assets/GUIScript.cs:22)
```

I have tried changing code, looking up solutions, the API for `HtmlDocument`, and how to fix `NullReferenceExceptions`, but for some reason I cannot figure out why I am getting a `NullReferenceException`. This problem has been holding me back for a week or two now and I need to move on with my project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If I've counted correctly, this is line 32:

```
return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title=input]").InnerText
```

That means either `doc.DocumentNode` is null or `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title=input]")` is returning null.

If it is the former, check you are receiving an actual document back. Your URL may not be encoded correctly. See also [why HTML Agility Pack HtmlDocument.DocumentNode is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139156/why-html-agility-pack-htmldocument-documentnode-is-null)

If it is the latter, it could be something odd happening with XPath. I don't know how relevant this is as `DocumentNode` should be the root of the document, the discussion at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/249129 could apply. According to this, '//' is searches from the root of *the document*, and you may have to try `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@title=input]")` instead (adding a `.` to the beginning of the string).

Debugging the method and seeing exactly the values of these calls will finish the job.

Comment: Document.SelectSingleNode does not compile because SelectSingleNode is not a valid method. It needs DocumentNode in order to access SelectSingleNode.

Comment: @CameronBarge Sorry, typo. I just meant to add a dot to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to retrieve? I opened the url you are using and did a simple find for `title=input` and returned nothing. I am guesing that your are looking for the translation of Hola, being Hello?

If so I did this in a console app. Hope this helps.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Input = "Hola";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=Hola&langpair=es|en");

        string definition = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//span[@title='{0}']",Input)).InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(definition);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

EDIT: Just realised you weren't looking for `title=input` but `title=Hola`. As you see in my code try `String.Format(("//span[@title='{0}']",Input)`. That will insert the text of the variable `Input` into the string line.