# SelectSingleNode Html Document

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

Currently I am dealing with an HtmlDocument in c# from a website:

```
return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title=input]").InnerText;
```

I want to get the inner text from a span with the title "input". Above is my current code but I receive a NullReferenceException when trying to run it. What should my implicit parameter be in order to retrieve the text from "input"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title='"+input+"']").InnerText;
```

Because input is not a string, it has to be concatenated to fit the parameters. Thanks for all of you help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to delimit strings with quotes in XPath expressions:

```
return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title='input']").InnerText;
```

Plain `input` will try to match a node by that name and substitute its value.

Comment: After changing my code to: return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@title='input']").InnerText; I still received the same error.

Comment: You can look at my full code for my program here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031757/nullreferenceexception-with-htmldocument-reference-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Cameron, well, that means there is no `<span>` element whose `title` attribute is equal to the string `'input'` in your document. *(Update: I just noticed your `.` token before `//`, that's not the same thing, in that case it means there is no matching `<span>` element under the current one.)*

Comment: I fixed it my doing ("//span[@title='"+input+"']") The reason is that input is not a string, and therefore needs to be concatenated. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `span` element with `title` attribute exists with value as 'input' in your `HtmlDocument` object of `HtmlAgilityPack`.

For proper checking, try this piece of code:

```
if (doc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title='input']");

    if (span != null)
        return span.InnerText;
}
```